# Grails, thread, autowried service

Tags: multithreading, grails, redis, executor

I have autowired a redisService (@Transactional) in my class. I have another workerThread class which implements runnable and it should use the Redis connection from my previous class to store some data in DB. How can I use the same redisService object of the first class in my worker thread class?

Answer (score 0):

You can wire your worker thread as a bean in resources.groovy and pass it a ref to the redisService.

```
workerThread(WorkerThread) {
  redisService = ref('redisService')
}
```

That is, if you're getting a handle on your workerThread through dependency injection. If you're instantiating it on your own, you can get a handle on the Spring application context through the static Holders class to manually extract the bean:

```
Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean("redisService")
```

The latter is a bad idea, but makes that scenario doable.

Good luck!